# Change Bar Button Image from Attribute Inspector List in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

When a bar button (Play) belonging to the toolbar is pressed I want to change its icon to a Pause image. 
The Play image is set when button is first created under the Attribute Inspector for the Bar Button Identifier.

The pause image I am trying to change the image too  is also from the drop list under identifier .

I have tried created a outlet reference to the button and called the appropriate method but  am stuck when trying to pass the UIIMage parameter as do not know how to reference the pause image found under Inspector drop down list.

```
@IBOutlet weak var PauseBarButtonOulet: UIBarButtonItem!

PauseBarButtonOulet.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(UIIMage?, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default);
```

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the button style like this:

```
//setButton to play
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "TheMethodThatTheButtonShouldCall"), animated: true)
//setButton to pause
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Pause, target: self, action: "TheMethodThatTheButtonShouldCall"), animated: true)
```

Or if the pause icon is your own custom pause image file, get the image like this:

Use `UIImage(named:"imageFileName.png")`

```
var image : UIImage = UIImage(named:"ImageName")
```

Comment: Ok is that for a image in assists?but how do I reference a image from the Attribute Imspector/Identifer drop down list?

Comment: This is if your image is one you put into your project as An image file.

Comment: Tried but nothing happened and no exceptions thrown. Also is it possible to change an item in a toolbar?

Comment: What exception gets thrown?

Comment: Yep, same no change, no exceptions

Comment: You do have a navigation controllers managing your view right?

Comment: Not sure what u mean by that . New to iOS. The buttons in question are within a navigation bar, they are stop/start buttons for a NSTimer in a stop watch app

Comment: That is ok, in your storyboard is there a navigation controller pointing to your view controller in question?

Comment: Make sure you drag a navigation item on to your navigation bar then try again and let me know :)

Comment: Try this: 1. Add an outlet  @IBOutlet var navigationItemInView:UINavigationItem! 2. drag a UINavigation item into your navigation bar and connect the outlet. 3. call navigationItemInView.setLeftBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Play, target: self, action: "TheMethodThatTheButtonShouldCall"), animated: true)

Comment: Should a bar button not be a IBAction rather than a IBOutlet?

Comment: No the An IBOutlet is to reference An object and IBAction is to be sent to a method to execute.